# How to annotate wrapper for Optional[int]? Difficulty: when it's a parameter

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I can't seem to find an acceptable annotation for a variable that receives a value that is either: a) function returning `int` or b) `None`.  The wrinkle is that the function returns a value that is an optional keyword parameter of the parent function, so it was previously declared as `Optional[int]`.  However, the runtime assignment guarantees that the function will never *return* `None`.

If I remove the annotation, `mypy` accepts it as golden.  But I'd prefer to use some (acceptable) annotation.  In for a penny, in for a pound...

My code:

```py
from typing import Optional, Callable


def myfun(p1: Optional[int] = None):
    # mypy complains about this
    dyn_p1:Optional[Callable[[], int]] = (lambda: p1) if p1 else None

    # ... but has no problem with this
    # dyn_p1 = (lambda: p1) if p1 else None

    otherFun(dyn_p1)


# I expect the parameter annotation here to be checked at the point of invocation above.
def otherFun(dyn_p1: Optional[Callable[[], int]]):
    pass
```

Here's the `mypy` error:

```sh
PS $ mypy .\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts\test1.py
prompt_toolkit\shortcuts\test1.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Callable[[], Optional[int]]]", variable has type "Optional[Callable[[], int]]")
prompt_toolkit\shortcuts\test1.py:6: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[int]", expected "int")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

# comment out the first dyn_p1 and uncomment the second, run again:
PS $ mypy .\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts\test1.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug. If I declare `p1_`  as `def p1_() -> int: pass` and do `dyn_p1 = p1_ if p1 else None`, `mypy` has no problem with that. Something about the use of `lambda` here is confusing `mypy`.

Comment: Minor tip unrelated to the main answer: be careful with `if p1`. That will go to `else` for any Falsey value. In particular, if `p1` were 0, `dyn_p1` would be None instead of a function waiting to return 0. If that's not what you want, be explicit in using `if p1 is not None`.

Answer (score 1):

It simply needs to be changed as follows

```
from typing import Optional, Callable


def myfun(p1: Optional[int] = None):
    dyn_p1: Optional[Callable[[], Optional[int]]] = (lambda: p1) if p1 else None
    otherFun(dyn_p1)


def otherFun(dyn_p1: Optional[Callable[[], Optional[int]]]):
    pass
```

This is because you've clearly defined p1 to be an optional int, and therefore if p1 is to be returned by the lambda, then dyn_p1 must be able to return an optional int, not just an int.

Now running mypy

```
(venv) ➜  pythonProject mypy okay.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Although adding Optional satisfies MyPy in the minimal example, I don't imagine it is the desired behaviour. (especially for otherFun)

Comment: Either he has to declare the function to return an optional, _or_ he can change the function so that it returns an int, not an optional. The library is working as intended.

Comment: MyPy is working as designed, yes. To me, it's clear in the question that the intended behaviour of the code in the question is to create a callable that returns an int. MyPy is correctly flagging that the callable might instead return `None`. In that situation, your second solution is the better one. You might even say changing the function to ensure it verifiably doesn't give None is fixing a bug which MyPy helped find, whereas massaging the signatures is more like changing the specification to declare that bug a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I (kinda) don't think the issue here is your lambda. I think it's actually `p1`.

Suppose you had instead

```
def myfun(p1: int = 5):
    dyn_p1:Optional[Callable[[], int]] = (lambda: p1) if p1 > 0 else None
```

After all, the lambda returns `p1`. `p1` is an integer. The lambda returns an integer. The lambda is `Callable[[], int]`. Except when it's None, and Optional makes everything happy.

In your case, `p1` isn't an `int`. It's an `Optional[int]`. So MyPy correctly infers that it's a `Callable[[], Optional[int]]`. That disagrees with the type hint, so it squawks.

Now you might say "But MyPy should be able to do code flow analysis, and know that the lambda only gets asigned in the case where `p1` isn't None."

Which... is true. And MyPy can do some code flow analysis. For example, it's fine with this:

```
def test(p1: Optional[int]) -> None:
    p2: Union[int, str] = p1 if p1 is not None else "Fail"
```

I suspect the catch here is that **lambdas are late bound**. That is, although you've checked that your `p1` is not `None` at the point where you assign it, it's still entirely typing legal to set it back to `None` after you create `dyn_p1`.

If you had the code

```
def myfun(p1: Optional[int] = None):
    dyn_p1:Optional[Callable[[], int]] = (lambda: p1) if p1 else None
    p1 = None
    return dyn_p1()
myfun(5)
```

even though `p1` starts as an int, the result would be `None` because that's what `p1` is at the point the lambda is executed.

MyPy doesn't analyse control flow to ensure this variable never gets changed to something type-legal. Instead it warns you that easy-to-forget Python rules mean that might not be as predictable as it looks at first sight.

One thing you could do is introduce another variable which is annotated as `int`. Because it would not be legal to change the new variable to `None`, MyPy can stopy worrying.

```
def myfun(p1: Optional[int] = None):
    if p1 is not None:
        p1_: int = p1
        dyn_p1:Optional[Callable[[], int]] = (lambda: p1_)
    else:
        dyn_p1 = None
    otherFun(dyn_p1)
```

---

Rather ironically, in your example of it works if you don't check, MyPy doesn't notice the late binding problem. It's not marking it as `Any` or anything; it actually infers the type you wanted to tell it!

```
def test(p1: Optional[int] = 5) -> int:
    dyn_p1 = (lambda: p1) if p1 else None
    reveal_type(dyn_p1)
    p1 = None
    reveal_type(dyn_p1)
    return dyn_p1() if dyn_p1 is not None else 0
```

This type checks fine. The revealed type is 'Union[def () -> builtins.int, None]' both times (which is MyPy spelling of Optional[Callable[[], int]]). But if you actually call it, it sneaks through an unauthorised `None`.

Comment: I have filed a bug against this here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9658